# New to <dirent.h>, trying to access data in a directory

Tags: c++, directory, opendir, istringstream, dirent.h

I've never used `dirent.h` before. I was using istringstream to read through text files (singular), but have needed to try to revise the program to read in multiple text files in a directory. This is where I tried implementing dirent, but it's not working.

Maybe I can't use it with the stringstream? Please advise.

I've taken out the fluffy stuff that I'm doing with the words for readability. This *was* working perfectly for one file, until I added the dirent.h stuff.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>  // for istringstream
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void main(){

    string fileName;
    istringstream strLine;
    const string Punctuation = "-,.;:?\"'!@#$%^&*[]{}|";
    const char *commonWords[] = {"AND","IS","OR","ARE","THE","A","AN",""};
    string line, word;
    int currentLine = 0;
    int hashValue = 0;

    //// these variables were added to new code //////

    struct dirent *pent = NULL;
    DIR *pdir = NULL; // pointer to the directory
    pdir = opendir("documents");

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////


    while(pent = readdir(pdir)){

        // read in values line by line, then word by word
        while(getline(cin,line)){
            ++currentLine;

            strLine.clear();
            strLine.str(line);

            while(strLine >> word){

                        // insert the words into a table

            }

        } // end getline

        //print the words in the table

    closedir(pdir);

    }
```

Comment: Note that `void main()` is not one of the valid prototypes for the main program in C++ (and is non-standard in C).

Comment: hi, I'm very sorry, I wasn't aware about the upvoting ! Have gone back and remedied this. Thank you for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `int main()` and not `void main()`.

You should be error checking the call to `opendir()`.

You will need to open a file instead of using `cin` to read the contents of the file.  And, of course, you will need to ensure that it is closed appropriately (which might be by doing nothing and letting a destructor do its stuff).

Note that the file name will be a combination of the directory name (`"documents"`) and the file name returned by `readdir()`.

Note too that you should probably check for directories (or, at least, for `"."` and `".."`, the current and parent directories).

The book ["Ruminations on C++"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201423391) by Andrew Koenig and Barbara Moo has a chapter that discusses how to wrap the `opendir()` family of functions in C++ to make them behave better for a C++ program.

---

Heather asks:

> What do I put in `getline()` instead of `cin`?

The code at the moment reads from standard input, aka `cin` at the moment.  That means that if you launch your program with `./a.out < program.cpp`, it will read your `program.cpp` file, regardless of what it finds in the directory.  So, you need to create a new input file stream based on the file you've found with `readdir()`:

```
while (pent = readdir(pdir))
{
    ...create name from "documents" and pent->d_name
    ...check that name is not a directory
    ...open the file for reading (only) and check that it succeeded
    ...use a variable such as fin for the file stream
    // read in values line by line, then word by word
    while (getline(fin, line))
    {
         ...processing of lines as before...
    }
}
```

You probably can get away with just opening the directories since the first read operation (via `getline()`) will fail (but you should probably arrange to skip the `.` and `..` directory entries based on their name).  If `fin` is a local variable in the loop, then when the outer loop cycles around, `fin` will be destroyed, which should close the file.

Comment: ok so I've changed void to int (not sure why I did this in the first place tbh.)  and also put in the error checks. The directory "documents" is correct, I had this working before with just printing out the names of the documents.. so I think it's right.

So.. I'm confused, what do I put in getline() instead of cin? These are very much confusing me.